# View and print unthreaded email message bodies consecutively without email trailers?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email, thunderbird, gmail

I am using Windows 10. In Outlook desktop app, Thunderbird, or Gmail web app, is there a way to view and print a continuous stream of email messages, including body but excluding the historical email trails at the end of each message? There may be a page break between messages (ideally I can control that).

I'm interested in viewing and printing a continuous stream of such messages in a folder, perhaps sorted by date. The counterpart to a folder in the webmail interface to Gmail is a tag, possibly a nested tag.

**Context** By historical trailers, I mean that if someone else sent you an email reply or forward that includes the original message, then that "historical" content is part of the message body, and will get printed.  If I want to print out a record of communications, the trailers get longer with each message and the majority of content will be trailers. There is no need for trailers if the messages are all printed out (in chronological order rather than reverse order as per the trailers).

**P.S.** Thunberbird's Supernova will save to separate text files per message or print to separate PDFs per message. Outlook 2019 will print to a single PDF file with each message starting a new page and retaining the historical email trailers.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by trailers? If someone else sent you an email reply or forward that includes the original message, then that "historical" content is part of the message body, and will get printed.

Comment: So is the answer that such trailers cannot be cut out?  The thing is, if I print out a record of communications, the trailers get longer with each message and the majority of content will be trailers.  There is no need for trailers if the messages are all printed out (in chronological order rather than reverse order as per the trailers).

Comment: Correct, they won't get cut automatically. Consider how some email clients will actually edit the content from previous emails (like how ios mail indents by default); there's no real way for your client to understand what is or is not "new" information. Depending on your workflow, Outlook's conversation view might help you print out only the newest email from each chain, which usually contains the previous messages

Answer (score 1):

The print options in Outlook desktop client are quite limited and seems cannot meet your requirement in all details. But you can try cutting off most of the unnecessary trailers by setting the pages instead of printing out all:

[image]

Comment: Thjanks, but it's easier to select pages for removal interactively using either Foxit PDF Editor of Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: Okay, then it might be better to use Foxit PDF editor to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is very ugly.  I printed all emails to a single PDF, targeting a logical page size of 5"W x 5"H paper.  I then went through the pages using a PDF editor (e.g., Acrobat or Foxit) and removed the pages that delved too far into historical email.  A little bit of message history was fine (and in fact helpful). Because the 5"x5" logical pages could fit 2 per Letter sized physical page, I used `psnup` to double up them up.  This isn't quite the continuous printout of emails that I wanted, but it did ensure that the gap left by excised pages was never more than half the height of a Letter sized page.